# Comands on Prestashop Module Development don't work

Tags: symfony, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a module for Prestashop 1.7. I need to use Command functionality into it. I been follow the steps put in the documentation page (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/commands/) and try to search another sites but i can't find a solution.

when i use the command example:

> ./bin/console your-module:export

i get this message:

> There are no commands defined in the "mymodule" namespace.

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work with the upcoming Prestashop 1.7.5.0

Comment: Available in a week or so... :-)